# Liquid Versus Aqueous States?

Tags: aqueous-solution, liquids

I am studying ionic equations and have encountered the statement of the phase of matter in the equation since ionic substances tend to react differently based on their phase.

I know that

(l) state is when the substance itself is a liquid
(aq) state is when we put the substance in an aqueous solutions, most commonly water.

But I don't know

1) Why and when would you use one state over the other. (Answered)

2) How do you define the concentration when you say (aq) state? Is it predefined/can be computed based on the substance or reaction or is it irrelevant?

Comment: An *aqueous solution* is water based. You might have other liquids like acetic acid or ethanol in the solution too, so water doesn't have to be the only liquid. Does this answer you question?

Comment: Almost. See question 2.

Comment: One could theorize that the liquid phase must be at least 50 mole % water to be an aqueous phase, but that certainly oversimplifies the situation. I'd say that if the reactions are what you'd expect in a water solution then it is an aqueous phase.

Comment: Perhaps I can be a little more helpful, but only by introducing another factor. If we're using a aqueous Ksp for example we'll typically use concentrations, but it is really activities of the ions that should be used for the equation. So for an aqueous solution I'd typically assume the concentration simplification. So for a 40 mole % solution of ethanol, I wouldn't expect good agreement with the Ksp equation even though the solution is more than 50 mole % water. I'd expect that you'd have to use activities which would greatly complicate the mathematics.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please make your comments into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2) How do you define the concentration when you say (aq) state? Is it predefined/can be computed based on the substance or reaction or is it irrelevant?

When a reaction equation is written down, one usually has a specific process (initial and final states including concentrations) in mind. When this information is not provided, and when it is not say the objective of a (e.g. textbook) question to identify the concentrations, it is usually safe (sometimes even necessary) to assume that the change is between ideal reference states.

Tabulated thermodynamic data such as heats of formation usually refer to ideal standard states, which in the case of a heat of formation of an aqueous solution corresponds to a pressure of 1 bar, and an ideal solution (with the solute having the same properties as in an infinitely dilute solution) at either 1 molal or 1 molar concentration of the solute.

So for instance the process (taken from another answer - thanks @Farooq)

$$\ce{HCl (g) -> H+ (aq) + Cl- (aq)}$$

refers to transfer of a gas molecule into a 1 M or 1 molal solution, if the process refers to standard states (as tabulated data usually does).
During the transfer, the properties of the bulk solvent do not change, and so the solvent does not appear explicitly in the equation.

It can be hard to understand how a 1 molar or 1 molal solution can simultaneously have the properties of an infinitely dilute solution. That's because we extrapolate from the data for an infinitely dilute state to a finite (1 M or 1 molal) concentration, using Henry's or Raoult's law.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it predefined/can be computed based on the substance or is it
>   irrelevant?

The state symbols, l, s, g, (aq), as they are called are nothing but qualitative descriptors. They have nothing to do with concentrations. It is a good point when do we distinguish (l) and (aq)? You have already answered it. When a given component in the equation is a pure liquid and it is participating in a reaction, you would prefer to write "l". If a reactant or a product is dissolved in water, it is better to write (aq). Consider hydrogen chloride gas being dissolved in pure water to yield hydrochloric acid solution.

e.g. HCl (g) + H2O (l) -> H3O+ (aq) + Cl- (aq)

Comment: So if you gave me an equation with one or more aqueous reactants, are you saying I would be able to perform the reaction with any concentration of aq since the reaction does not depend on it?

Comment: How does a gas dissolve in water? That seems quite interesting and weird.

Comment: 1) Yes, you are right. (aq) is just a medium. Reaction certainly depends on the nature of a medium. If gases such as oxygen did not dissolve in water, all fishes would be dead in the oceans and seas. Don't forget Coke which has CO2 dissolved in sugary water. HCl gas is extremely soluble in water.